# data.table: subsetting a grouping variable in j with keyby

Tags: r, data.table, subset

Say I have this dataset

```
test <- data.table(X = rep(1, 3), Y = rep("a", 3))
```

which gives us

```
test
#   X Y
#1: 1 a
#2: 1 a
#3: 1 a
```

I'm wondering why

```
test[, X[Y == "a"], keyby = .(X)]
```

gives

```
#   X V1
#1: 1  1
#2: 1 NA
#3: 1 NA
```

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: Did you meant to do `test[Y == 'a', .SD, keyby = .(X)]` or `test[,  .SD[Y == "a"], keyby = .(X)]`

Comment: I did mean test[, X[Y == "a"], keyby = .(X)] because I would like to do something like test[, uniqueN(X[Y == "a"]), keyby = .(X)]. In whixh case, I expect 1 as result but it gives 2 as unique count.

Comment: Not sure why you want to use the grouping column to subset it because grouping column output a single element while the other Y == 'a', returns 3 and thus it is filled with NA (unless you replicate the X

Comment: It's standard R behavior for out-of-bounds indexing. See [R Intro3.4.1 Indexing by vectors](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Indexing-by-vectors): "If `i` is positive and exceeds `length(x)` then the corresponding selection is `NA`", together with the fact that inside each group, the grouping variable is of length 1 (see [FAQ 2.10](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#inside-each-group-why-are-the-group-variables-length-1))

Comment: You're right. But I'm still wondering why test[, X[Y == "a"], keyby = .(X)] gives this answer instead of simply #X V1 #1 1.

Comment: @Henrik test[, Y == "a", keyby = .(X)] gives TRUE TRUE TRUE, so why test[, X[Y == "a"], keyby = .(X)] does not give #X V1 #1 1 #1 1 #1 1?

Comment: Indeed. The length of the logical index (`i`) is 3. The length of the grouping variable inside each group is 1 (`x`, the vector you try to index; again, see FAQ): "If `i` is positive (yes, here `i` is 3) and exceeds `length(x)` (yes it does, length index vector `i` is 3, length of vector to be indexed `x` is 1) then the corresponding selection is `NA`

Comment: Side-note: thanks for posting such a small, illustrative toy data set!

Comment: Thank you very much @Henrik

Comment: There are some related GitHub posts. Maybe [this one](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3103) is most related and [this one](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4079) is still open

Answer (score 1):

If you run `X` and `Y=="a"` separately

```
> test[, X, keyby = .(X)]
   X X
1: 1 1

> test[, Y == "a", keyby = .(X)]
   X   V1
1: 1 TRUE
2: 1 TRUE
3: 1 TRUE
```

you will see that, the first one gives numeric value `1` of length 1, and the second one gives logical values `TRUE` of length 3.

Since you don't have matched lengths for subsetting, you will obtain `NA`s to fill in the corresponding places, e.g.,

```
> 1[rep(TRUE,3)]
[1]  1 NA NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, its complicated, in a way.

It has to do with what `X` is inside a grouping.

Consider these variations:

| description | expression |
| --- | --- |
| **Yours** | test[, `X[Y == "a"]`, keyby=.(X) ] |
| **X only** | test[, `X`, keyby=.(X) ] |
| **Y=="a" only** | test[, `Y == "a"`, keyby=.(X) ] |

X only gives:

```
> test[, X, keyby=.(X) ]
   X X
1: 1 1
```

This is what 'X' is inside your grouping. Only that one value.

The third expression:

```
> test[, Y == "a", keyby=.(X) ]
   X   V1
1: 1 TRUE
2: 1 TRUE
3: 1 TRUE
```

There you see what `Y == "a"` looks like inside your grouping.

If you combine these, to do: `X[ Y == "a" ]` inside your grouping, you effectively do:

```r
X <- 1
X[ c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE) ]
```

`X` having only one value, but are asked to return the first, second and third values, will give you its one value and 2 NA's, which is what you see.

Answer (score 0):

It returns `2` in `uniqueN` because there are two values - 1) the 'X' grouping  value 1 and the `NA` filled up.  We could use `na.rm = TRUE` in `uniqueN`

```
test[, uniqueN(X[Y == "a"],  na.rm = TRUE), keyby = .(X)]
#   X V1
#1: 1  1
```

As mentioned in @ThomasIsCoding post, it the mismatch in `length` between the logical vector and the `length` of grouping variable (which returns length 1) cause the filling of additional TRUE positions with NA.  An option would be to `rep`licate

```
test[, rep(X, .N)[Y == "a"], keyby = .(X)]
#   X V1
#1: 1  1
#2: 1  1
#3: 1  1
```